# Communication between Web Services failed before sooner than the Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have two Web services:
The first one is REST service, another - SOAP.
Into REST service the `web.config` I have next section:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
    receiveTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
<client>
   <endpoint address="THE URL"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IMyService"
        contract="MyWS.IMyService" name="BasicHttpsBinding_IMyService" />
</client>
```

where the `THE URL` is the URL to the SOAP Service. In it `web.config` I have:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding sendTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

But... the connections between both services failes after 5 minutes with error:

> Exception type: System.TimeoutException
>
> Message: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   01:00:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or
>   increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Based on the error, it seems that timeout values are valid, but why this happened?
Do I miss any configuration?
Also, the both services are on different machines in the private network.

Thank you!

Comment: Who knows? Maybe you have long operation on server side.

Comment: Yes, the "work" on the SOAP service takes more than 5 minutes time, but why the connection is closed with exception after 5 minutes when Timeout settings are set to 1 hour?

Comment: Maybe it is your IIS who is set to timeout in 5 minutes.